# Iterate 2 arrays in knockout template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In viewmodel, I have 2 arrays. say arr1 and arr2. I want to iterate both the arrays and render view accordingly in html template.

e.g. I want to write equivalent of following js code in html.

```
for(var i = 0; i< arr1.length; i++){
 for(var j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
   if(arr1[i] == 'x' && arr2[j] == 'y'){
     //render input field
   }
   if(arr1[i] == 'w' && arr2[j] == 'z'){
     //render checkbox
   }
 }
}
```

I want to achieve the same in following html.

```
<div data-bind="foreach : arr1">
 <!-- ko foreach: arr2 -->

// conditions to be added here for rendering input field or checkbox
 <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

How can I give the condition for comparing arr1 and arr2 values in html as is done in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: arr1, as: 'a' }">
  <!-- ko foreach: { data: $parent.arr2, as: 'b' } -->
    // You should be able to reference 'a' and 'b' here
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The `$parent.` is needed to reference outside the scope of the first foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [*if binding*][1] on *knockoutjs* to get same approach that was applyed on your *javascript* sample.

I've created an example of how to use the nested *foreach binding and *if binding*.

**JS**

```
var vm = {  
    array1 : ko.observableArray(['x', 'y', 'z']), 
    array2: ko.observableArray([1,2,3]) 
}; 
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: array1, as: 'arr1' }">
  <!-- ko foreach: { data: $root.array2, as: 'arr2' } -->
    <label data-bind="text: arr1"></label>
    <div data-bind="if: arr2  == 1">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: arr2" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: arr2  == 2">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: arr2  == 3">
      <select></select>
    </div>    
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/6evL0n2c/3/